# Dynamically creating Expandoobject using data from another class

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a ***Metadata*** class ***AccountData*** which holds mock data for automated testing.

I am using subsets of this data to insert into various tables in the database.

**Eg. 1**

```
dynamic table1 = new ExpandoObject();
table1 .AccountId = AccountId;
table1 .DateOfBirth = AccountData.DateOfBirth;
table1 .Gender = AccountData.Gender;
table1 .Title = 0;
....etc
```

**Eg. 2**

```
dynamic table2 = new ExpandoObject();
table2 .Forename = AccountData.Forename;
table2 .Surname = AccountData.Surname;
table2 .HomePhone = AccountData.HomePhone;
table2 .MobilePhone = AccountData.MobilePhone;
... etc
```

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to generate DynamicObjects? I am thinking of a function like

```
private static ExpandoObject Generatedynamic(List<String> ColumnsToInclude)
{
//todo
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you using dynamic objects? Would it be possible to use a simple Dictionary<string,object> instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpandoObject implements IDictionary<T,Y> so you can use it's Add () method like any other dictionary.

There is a sample in one of my Github projects -> https://github.com/tucaz/XmlToObjectParser/blob/master/trunk/src/XmlToObjectParser/XmlToObjectParser.cs

Comment: Thanks tucasz

I was able to use reflection and dictionary to build up my object dynamically!